# error : invalid literal for int() with base 10: b'20 Feb'

Tags: python, django, wagtail, datefield

I am working with Wagtail and I am creating the model of the app.

```
publish_date = models.DateField(
        max_length=300,
        blank=True,
        null=True,
        default="20 Feb",
        verbose_name="First publish date",
        help_text="This shows the first publish date"
    )
```

I think the problem is that the field type is a DateField but the value that I am sending is '20 Feb'.

Any ideas?

Comment: can you be more clear about what you want to do?

Comment: Use a `datetime.date` object as `default`, not a string.

Comment: `datetime.date.today` you can use by importing `from datetime import datetime`.

Answer (score 2):

You can' t use a string, `DateField` requires a `datetime.date` object. If you always want the same date, you can write:

```py
import datetime
publish_date = models.DateField(
        max_length=300,
        blank=True,
        null=True,
        default=datetime.date(2022, 2, 20),  # Or another date
        verbose_name="First publish date",
        help_text="This shows the first publish date"
    )
```

If you want the current date as the default:

```
import datetime
publish_date = models.DateField(
        max_length=300,
        blank=True,
        null=True,
        default=datetime.date.today,
        verbose_name="First publish date",
        help_text="This shows the first publish date"
    )
```

If you support timezones you should use `django.utils.timezone` instead of `datetime`.